# Asynchronous fire and forget in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, multithreading

Currently I am about to develop logging for a c# application into a SQL server table.

I have a designated class called `Logger` that has a static method `writeToLog()`.

I just want to call that static function without block the calling thread.

How is this possible in C# clean and fast?

The functions don't return anything they are just fire and forget.

Thanks for you advice

Comment: Task.Run(writeToLog);

Comment: Don't re-invent the wheel, there are tons of free logging libraries out there that have solved all the problems you are going to run in to. For example Log4Net can [write directly to a Sql server as the destination of the log](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/log4net-1.2.13/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender.html).

Comment: Logging should not be `fired and forgotten`, unless you are handling it on a background worker thread. If you `fire and forget` it, it might change order, and you don't want that.

Comment: @tuxmania perhaps instead of "fire-and-forget" you mean "queue for processing in the background"? That's already available in [ActionBlock<T>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194684(v=vs.110).aspx). Still, don't reinvent the wheel. There's a lot more to logging than simply writing something to a file or database

Comment: Order is unimportant since the method fills a datetime column that is filled by c# code (when calling the function) with DateTime.Now.
However i will look into some frameworks.

Thing is they need changes asap and is has to work with arbitrary table design, no extra columns from a framework can be there.

Answer (score 0):

There is the chance that the serveral available logging libraries out there have spent some thoughts about performance.

If you still need to develop a light weight solution yourself I think of two ways.

1.) Create a `Task` that runs the logging function, without awaiting them

2.) The Log-Method saves the Log-Information in a queue that is written to the SQL-database with a background thread.

I would recommend the second way, because the logging itself can be done in a synchronous function call without the Task creation overhead.

Another argument for this approach is that it is possible to gurantee the order of log messages. By using a Task for each single message the order of execution is not defined.

And a last argument: It might be more performant to write blocks of messages to the SQL table. By using the queue you will be able write messages in a bulk operation.

Comment: Forcing the application to always have a dedicated thread for logging is quite likely to be a *notably* higher overhead than the overhead of creating some `Task` objects and leveraging the thread pool.  Creating a new `Task` costs basically nothing, even if you multiply it by several thousand instances, starting a new `Thread`, and forcing it to stay active for the entirety of the application's lifetime, is rather expensive.

Comment: @Servy - thanks for your hint; I have added additional arguments.

Comment: @Servy I don't agree on that. I think a single thread that handles logging, can be much more efficient than multiple tasks running simultaneously. Also multiple logging actions can be handled bulk. Errors while persisting logs, can be handled synchronously.

Comment: @rboe It's *very* easy to serialize the tasks, if that's important to you.  You don't need a dedicated thread for that.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen You don't need to have a dedicated thread to batch the operations and perform them all at once.  Frameworks that build on the TPL (such as reactive extensions, or TPL dataflow) even make this very easy.  As for error logging, that's not really notably different either way.  You certainly don't need a dedicated thread to handle errors while logging.

Comment: Never worked with `reactive extensions`, so can't judge on that. I'll look it up.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen Just to clarify, you wouldn't need a framework like that in order to batch asynchronous operations together, it just has tools in place already to trivially do it.  You could do it yourself if you wanted to, and if you're building a logging framework, it'd be the kind of thing that would be worth doing.

Comment: [ActionBlock<T>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194684(v=vs.110).aspx) makes it trivial to post log messages to a buffer for storage in the background. Other classes in TPL dataflow provide batching, copying messages to multiple targets etc